# How to format Array in WordPress/PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, wordpress, for-loop

i have this forloop that give me a array result as shown below. but the result of the json format is weird it run out of place.can any one please help out here? tried change a few ways but fail when i change code to `$product_name[$prod_url][$i][$i]` they did join together but instead of giving me productname it become null. this way `$product_name[$i][[$prod_url][$i]]` it totally blank screen.

```
{
0: {
0: {
order_item_name: "12345678"
},
Permalink: "https://localhost/Test/?post_type=post&p=80"
},
1: {
0: {
order_item_name: "asdasdasda"
},
Permalink: "https://localhost/Test/?post_type=post&p=79"
},
2: {
0: {
order_item_name: "test"
},
Permalink: "https://localhost/Test/?post_type=post&p=9"
},
3: {
0: {
order_item_name: "test222222"
},
Permalink: "https://localhost/Test/?post_type=post&p=76"
},
status: "ok"
}
```

ForLoop

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($product_name); $i++){
                    $post_data[$i] = $product_name[$i]->order_item_name;
                    foreach ($post_data as $pd){
                        $pd = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_title = '$post_data[$i]' ");
                    }
                    foreach($pd as $pdd){
                        $prod_url[] = get_post_permalink($pdd);
                    }
                    $data_array[$i] = array($product_name[$i],"Permalink" => $prod_url[$i]);

                }
```

How can i format it to look like this : or better format

```
{
0: {
Product Name: "12345678",
Permalink: "https://localhost/Test/?post_type=post&p=80"
},
1: {
Product Name: "asdasdasda",
Permalink: "https://localhost/Test/?post_type=post&p=79"
},
2: {
Product Name: "test",
Permalink: "https://localhost/Test/?post_type=post&p=9"
},
3: {
Product Name: "test222222",
Permalink: "https://localhost/Test/?post_type=post&p=76"
},
status: "ok"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by trying to fill in every loop vars zzzzz

```
$data_array[$i] = array("Product Name"=>$post_data[$i],"Permalink" => $prod_url[$i]);
```